# Merge the json objects with same key value pair in a file using python

Tags: python, json, merge

I have a file with objects in it like below.

Eg: Input.txt

```
1. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K11HE-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K11HE-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1688668060"}

2. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K08JV-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K08JV-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714277379"}

3. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "ABCD", "Cs": "K20LT-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K20LT-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714278093"}

4. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K08OW-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K08OW-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714277380"}
```

The file contains thousands of rows.

I want to group all those json objects in the file, which has the same value for the key " Ti ".

Below is an example to elaborate more on my requirement.

You can see from the sample file above, there are 3 lines with the same value of for key "Ti". That is line 1, 2 and 4. They have all the value for "Ti" as "Q2".

I need a way to join those JSON objects, and I want to create an output file, that looks like below.

Eg: Output.txt

```
1. {"Cp": "[1000, 1000, 1000]", "Af": "['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS']", "Bp": "[150, 150, 150]", "Vt": "['channel', 'channel', 'channel']", "Ti": "['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2']", "Cs": "['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D' ]", "Tg": "['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD, 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD]", "Fd": "['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D']", "Pi": "['CHAF2','CHAF2','CHAF2']", "Gi": "['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']"}

2. {"Cp": "[1000, 1000, 1000]", "Af": "['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS']", "Bp": "[150, 150, 150]", "Vt": "['channel', 'channel', 'channel']", "Ti": "['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2']", "Cs": "['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D' ]", "Tg": "['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD, 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD]", "Fd": "['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D']", "Pi": "['CHAF2','CHAF2','CHAF2']", "Gi": "['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']"}

3. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "ABCD", "Cs": "K20LT-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K20LT-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714278093"}

4. {"Cp": "[1000, 1000, 1000]", "Af": "['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS']", "Bp": "[150, 150, 150]", "Vt": "['channel', 'channel', 'channel']", "Ti": "['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2']", "Cs": "['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D' ]", "Tg": "['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD, 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD]", "Fd": "['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D']", "Pi": "['CHAF2','CHAF2','CHAF2']", "Gi": "['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']"}
```

Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Comment: The easiest way I could think of is You can load the json into a dataframe and do a value manipulation by combining rows which have same "Ti" values and then convert the dataframe back to json. That would be easier than trying to manipulate the json as it is. It could be better if you share the raw json contents rather than formatting it in the question and also elaborate on what have you tried on your part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. convert string into dictionary
2. collect Ti values
3. loop over dictionary elements and collect data based on Ti

```
import re

raw_data = open('test.txt', 'r')

data_list = raw_data.read().splitlines()
data_list = list(filter(None, data_list))

# create list of Ti values
ti_list = []
for item in data_list:
    number = re.search('\d+\.', item).group(0)
    row = re.sub('\d+\. ', '', item)
    row_dictionary = eval(row)
    ti_list.append(row_dictionary.get('Ti'))


# collect data into new dictionary
data = {}
i = 1
for ti in ti_list:
    raw = {}
    for item in data_list:
        number = re.search('\d+\.', item).group(0)
        row = re.sub('\d+\. ', '', item)
        row_dictionary = eval(row)

        if row_dictionary.get('Ti') == ti:
            for key, value in row_dictionary.items():
                raw.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

    data[str(i)+'.'] = raw
    i += 1
```

**Output:**

```
1. {'Cp': ['1000', '1000', '1000'], 'Af': ['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS'], 'Bp': ['150', '150', '150'], 'Vt': ['channel', 'channel', 'channel'], 'Ti': ['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2'], 'Cs': ['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D'], 'Tg': ['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD'], 'Fd': ['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D'], 'Pi': ['CHAF2', 'CHAF2', 'CHAF2'], 'Gi': ['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']}
2. {'Cp': ['1000', '1000', '1000'], 'Af': ['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS'], 'Bp': ['150', '150', '150'], 'Vt': ['channel', 'channel', 'channel'], 'Ti': ['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2'], 'Cs': ['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D'], 'Tg': ['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD'], 'Fd': ['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D'], 'Pi': ['CHAF2', 'CHAF2', 'CHAF2'], 'Gi': ['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']}
3. {'Cp': ['1000'], 'Af': ['CBS'], 'Bp': ['150'], 'Vt': ['channel'], 'Ti': ['ABCD'], 'Cs': ['K20LT-D'], 'Tg': ['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD'], 'Fd': ['dish#K20LT-D'], 'Pi': ['CHAF2'], 'Gi': ['RV1714278093']}
4. {'Cp': ['1000', '1000', '1000'], 'Af': ['CBS', 'CBS', 'CBS'], 'Bp': ['150', '150', '150'], 'Vt': ['channel', 'channel', 'channel'], 'Ti': ['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2'], 'Cs': ['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D', 'K08OW-D'], 'Tg': ['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD'], 'Fd': ['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D', 'dish#K08OW-D'], 'Pi': ['CHAF2', 'CHAF2', 'CHAF2'], 'Gi': ['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379', 'RV1714277380']}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @KiranDas it means that you data row don't contains `number.`

Comment: You code works just fine. 

But, I see that you are considering the line number also.

In reality, my file doesn't have line numbers.  
I just used line number to highlight the explanation. 

Can you please suggest, how can we achieve this without considering the line numbers. 

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Below 3 lines show exactly, how the lines are present in the file

{"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K11HE-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K11HE-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1688668060"}
{"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K08JV-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K08JV-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714277379"}
{"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "ABCD", "Cs": "K20LT-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K20LT-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714278093"}

Comment: Yes Correct. 

Data row doesn't contain number..

However, If i insert the line number to all the rows, that should solve the issue.

Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: the code you have suggested, is throwing an error when it comes to the 10th line in the file.
Can you please help on resolving this ?

Comment: @@Zaraki Kenpachi

The code you have suggested is throwing an error when it comes to the 10th line in the file. 
It is able to read till the 9th line. But gives error after that.

It is able to handle lines with the single digit line number(i.e 1 to 9), but my file has thousands of lines.

Can you please help on resolving this ?

I am not able to paste the lines from file or error here, if you can simply use the lines i had posted in the question before, you can re create the issue. 

Just add more than 10 lines in the files, then you should be able to recreate the error.

Comment: @KiranDas you need to change each `\d\.` into `\d+\.`, Code updated.

Comment: ..Thank you.. this fixes the issue.

Comment: @@Zaraki Kenpachi . i am asking out of curiosity, may i know what all needs to be changed in the code to get the output like below.

Keeping the original dict as such and then adding the newly created dict into it.

INPUT:

1. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K11HE-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K11HE-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1688668060"}

2. {"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K08JV-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K08JV-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1714277379"}

Comment: OUTPUT: Keep the original dict and add the new dict to the original one but not merging values
{"Cp": "1000", "Af": "CBS", "Bp": "150", "Vt": "channel", "Ti": "Q2", "Cs": "K11HE-D", "Tg": "BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD", "Fd": "dish#K11HE-D", "Pi": "CHAF2", "Gi": "RV1688668060", 'Cp1': ['1000', '1000' ], 'Af1': ['CBS', 'CBS'], 'Bp1': ['150', '150'], 'Vt1': ['channel', 'channel'], 'Ti1': ['Q2', 'Q2'], 'Cs1': ['K11HE-D', 'K08JV-D'], 'Tg1': ['BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD', 'BROADCAST<>LOCAL<>HD'], 'Fd1': ['dish#K11HE-D', 'dish#K08JV-D'], 'Pi1': ['CHAF2', 'CHAF2'], 'Gi1': ['RV1688668060', 'RV1714277379']}